# Move Services From Servers in Aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-efs

Could anyone advise the best method(s) to move service from one EC2 instance to another? For example `Test-dev` we want to spin up and replace with `TEST` (server) but we want to get CRON services and scripts on the new instance. Additionally, we want to copy user profiles from the `Test-dev` instance onto this machine (`TEST (server)`).

any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

You can create an image based on your current instance (AMI) and then create another instance based on that image.

More info here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/tkv-create-ami-from-instance.html
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/launch-instance-custom-ami/